# Traversing the Parent-child relationship between objects: Part 2

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, tree, ecmascript-6

This code builds on the code in [the previous iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/200495/120114). All of the following tests should work:

```
let myTree = Tree.from({a:{b:{k:2}}});
myTree.a.b;                         // { k: 2 }
myTree.a === myTree.a.b.__parent__; // true
// adding properties
myTree.c = {d:{l:5}};               // {d: {l: 5}}
myTree.c.__parent__ === myTree;     // true
myTree.a.b.__parent__ = myTree.c;   // {d: {l: 5}}
myTree.c.b.k;                       // 2
myTree.a.b;                         // undefined
// moving branches to other trees.
let anotherTree = new Tree();
myTree.a.l = 3;
myTree.a.l;     // 3
myTree.a.__parent__ = anotherTree;
anotherTree.a;  // {l: 3}
myTree.a;       // undefined
anotherTree.a.__parent__ === anotherTree; // true
```

It also introduces the `Fragment` class, which behaves both like a tree and a branch in the fact that it can be assigned to both and have child properties.

Upon an object or primitive being assigned, it is immediately converted to a branch or a leaf, respectively.

All leaves are dynamically inherited.

Code:

```
const [Tree, Fragment] = ( function(){
    const LeafCache = Object.create( null ),
     genLeaf = ( CLASS ) => {
       return LeafCache[CLASS.name] || LeafCache[CLASS.name] = eval( `class Leaf extends ${CLASS.name} {
    constructor(val) {
        super(val);
    }
}; Leaf.prototype.__isleaf__ = true; Leaf` );
        },
     TARGET = Symbol( '__target__' ),
        HANDLER = Symbol( '__handler__' ),
        PROXY = Symbol( '__proxy__' ),
        ISTREE = Symbol( '__istree__' ),
        { assign, defineProperty, entries, setPrototypeOf } = Object,
        { hasOwnProperty } = {},
        convert = ( obj ) => {
          let res = obj instanceof Branch ? obj : new Branch( obj );
          for( const key in obj ) {
            const value = obj[key];
            if( hasOwnProperty.call( obj, key ) ) {
              if( '__isfragment__' !== key ) {
                if( typeof value === 'object' ) {
                    res[key] = convert( value );
                    Object.defineProperty( res[key], '__parent__', {
                      value: res[PROXY],
                      configurable: false,
                      protected: false
                    } );
                } else {
                  let val;
                  res[key] = new Proxy( val = new ( genLeaf( value.constructor ) )( value ), genHandler( val ) );
                }
              }
            }
          }
          return res;
        },
        getKey = ( obj, val ) => {
          for( const key in obj ) {
            const value = obj[key];
            if( value[TARGET] === val ) {
              return key;
            }
          }
        };
    let genHandler = ( _target ) => {
        return ( function(){
            let res;
            const _raw = __raw__.bind( _target ),
                _keys = {
                    '__raw__': _raw,
                    [ISTREE]: true,
                    [TARGET]: _target,
                    get [PROXY]() {
                        return res.proxy;
                    },
                    get [HANDLER]() {
                        return res;
                    }
                };
            res = {
                set: ( target, prop, value ) => {
                    if( prop === '__parent__' ) {
                        if( _keys[PROXY] instanceof Fragment ) {
                            throw TypeError( 'Cannot set __parent__ on fragments.' );
                        } else if( typeof value === 'object' && value[ISTREE] ) {
                            const key = getKey( target.__parent__, target );
                            if( target.__parent__[key] ) {
                                delete target.__parent__[key];
                            }
                            value[key] = target;
                            return value;
                        } else {
                            throw TypeError( 'Cannot assign __parent__ to a non-tree value' );
                        }
                    }
                    if( typeof value === 'object' && value.constructor.name !== 'Leaf' ) {
                        value = convert( value );
                        if( value[PROXY] instanceof Tree ) {
                            throw TypeError( 'Cannot have a tree as a child of another tree.' );
                        }
                        value = convert( value );
                        defineProperty( value, '__parent__', {
                            value: _keys[PROXY],
                            configurable: false,
                            writable: true
                        } );
                    } else if ( typeof value !== 'object' ) {
                        let val;
                        value = new Proxy( val = new ( genLeaf( value.constructor ) )( value ), genHandler( val ) );
                    }
                    target[prop] = value;
                    return value;
                },
                get: ( target, prop ) => {
                   if( prop === 'toJSON' ) {
                     return _raw;
                   }
                   if( [HANDLER, PROXY, '__raw__', ISTREE, TARGET].includes( prop ) ) {
                     return _keys[prop];
                   }
                    return target[prop];
                }
            };
            return res;
        } )();
    };
    /**
     * Get the raw value of the tree, without all that proxy stuff.
     * @returns {Object} The raw object. Please not that objects will not be the same instances.
     * @memberof Tree#
     */
    function __raw__() {
        let res = setPrototypeOf( {}, this.__proto__ );
        for( const key in this ) {
            if( key.slice( 0, 2 ) === key.slice( -2 ) && key.slice( -2 ) === '__' ) {
            continue;
        } else {
                const value = this[key];
                if( hasOwnProperty.call( this, key ) ) {
                    res[key] = typeof value === 'object' ? __raw__.call( value[TARGET] ) : value;
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
    /**
     * A class that enables navigation from child properties to parent. WIP - currently figuring out how to make new properties.
     * For all purposes this functions as intended, but it doesn't print well in the console. It even perserves prototypes.
     * @property {(Branch|Leaf)} * Properties.
     */
    class Tree {
        /**
         * Constructs a new Tree instance.
         * @constructs Tree
         */
        constructor() {
            return Tree.from( {} );
        }
        /**
         * Attempt to create a tree from an existing object.
         * @param {Object} obj The object to convert to a tree.
         * @throws {TypeError} You probably passed it a primitive.
         * @returns {Tree} The resulting tree.
         */
        static from( obj ) {
            const self = {},
                res = new Proxy( setPrototypeOf( self, obj.__proto__ ), genHandler( self ) );
            defineProperty( res[HANDLER], 'proxy', {
                value: res,
                configurable: false,
                protected: true
            } );
            if( typeof obj !== 'object' ) {
                throw TypeError( 'Tree expects an object' );
            } else {
                for( const key in obj ) {
                    const value = obj[key];
                    let val;
                    res[key] = typeof value === 'object' ? convert( value ) : new Proxy( val = new ( genLeaf( value.constructor ) )( value ), genHandler( val ) );
                    console.log( res[key][TARGET] );
                }
            }
            defineProperty( res, '__istree__', {
                value: true,
                configurable: false,
                protected: true
            } );
            return res;
        }
        static [Symbol.hasInstance]( obj ) {
          return obj[ISTREE] && obj.__istree__ || false;
        }
    }
    /**
     * A class that behaves similar to a tree and similar to a branch. It can be added to a tree like a branch.
     * @class
     */
    class Fragment {
        /**
         * Construct a new fragment.
         * @constructs Fragment
         */
        constructor() {
            return Fragment.from( {} );
        }
        /**
         * Attempt to make a fragment from an existing object.
         * @param {Object} obj The object to use.
         * @returns {Fragment} The resulting fragment.
         */
        static from( obj ) {
            const self = {},
                res = new Proxy( setPrototypeOf( self, obj.__proto__ ), genHandler( self ) );
            defineProperty( res[HANDLER], 'proxy', {
             value: res,
             configurable: false,
             protected: true
            } );
            if( typeof obj !== 'object' ) {
                throw TypeError( 'Tree expects an object' );
            } else {
                  for( let key in obj ) {
                    let value = obj[key];
                    res[key] = typeof value === 'object' ? convert( value ) : value;
                  }
            }
            defineProperty( res, '__isfragment__', {
                value: true,
                configurable: false,
                protected: true
            } );
            return res;
        }
        static [Symbol.hasInstance]( obj ) {
          return obj[ISTREE] && obj.__isfragment__ || false;
        }
    }
    class Branch {
        constructor( obj ) {
          let self = {},
                res = new Proxy( setPrototypeOf( self, obj.__proto__ ), genHandler( self ) );
            defineProperty( res[HANDLER], 'proxy', {
                value: res,
                configurable: false,
                protected: true
            } );
            defineProperty( res, '__isbranch__', {
                value: true,
                configurable: false,
                protected: true
            } );
            return res;
        }
        static [Symbol.hasInstance]( obj ) {
          return obj[ISTREE] && obj.__isbranch__ || false;
        }
    }
    return [Tree, Fragment];
} )();
/**
 * A class that shows that an item is a terminal node. Parent properties cannot be accessed by this node.
 * @alias Brance
 * @class Leaf
 * @extends Primitive
 */
/**
 * A class that simply shows that it is an inner object of a Tree.
 * @alias Branch
 * @class Branch
 * @property {(Tree|Branch)} __parent__ The parent element. This can be changed to move the object to another tree or branch.
 */
```

<sub>This is an iterative review. Previous iteration: [Traversing the parent-child relationship between objects](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/200495/168361)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Errors

I tried this both in jsFiddle (with and without JS 1.7 and Babel) as well as NodeJS but saw a few errors. The first one was:

> ```
>   return LeafCache[CLASS.name] || LeafCache[CLASS.name] = eval( `class Leaf extends ${CLASS.name} {
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```
>
> ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

So then I tried wrapping the second conditional in parentheses and that appeared to get me past that error:

```
return LeafCache[CLASS.name] || (LeafCache[CLASS.name] = eval( `class Leaf extends ${CLASS.name} {
    constructor(val) {
        super(val);
    }
}; Leaf.prototype.__isleaf__ = true; Leaf` ));
```

But then I see another error:

> ```
>                Object.defineProperty( res[key], '__parent__', {
>                        ^
> ```
>
> TypeError: Cannot redefine property: __parent__

### Other feedback

Other than those errors I don't see much I would change - maybe a few places where variables can be declared using `const` instead of `let` - e.g. `genHandler`, `res` within the function `__raw__`, so as to avoid unintentional re-assignment...

Some of this code appears to be identical to the changes added in [revision 7](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/200495/7) to [your previous post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/200495/120114) but with the `Leaf` class added. Was that in response to the suggestion at the end of [rm-'s answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/200942/120114)?

> but still the code could be simplified a little bit, split into separate small utility functions, organized in a way to be easy to read from top to bottom, and such.<sup>[1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/200942/120114)</sup>

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/200942/120114</sub>

Comment: The Leaf class is mostly in response to the answer, yes, and also to show dynamic inheritance. Thanks. I think one more post should do this project. It'll be ready in about a week. or 2.